# Please Identify this Apple II Diagnostic Message: "IOU FLAG E5: 1 2 3 4 8"

Tags: apple-ii, diagnostics

Does anybody know the meaning of this message from the Apple IIe diagnostic?

```
IOU FLAG E5: 1 2 3 4 8
```

What are addressing the 1 2 3 4 8?

I’m pretty sure that IOU is the I/O chip, E5 is the location on the board.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the Apple Technical Information Library at https://mirrors.apple2.org.za/:

```
 IOU  FLAG E5:0  The 80VID switch didn't initialize
                 properly during reset.
              1  The ALTCHAR switch didn't initialize
                 properly during reset.
              2  The TEXT switch didn't initialize
                 properly during reset.
              3  The PAGE2 switch didn't initialize
                 properly during reset.
              4  The MIXMODE switch didn't initialize
                 properly during reset.
              5  The HIRES switch didn't initialize
                 properly during reset.
              6  The 80VID switch won't change.
              7  The ALTCHAR switch won't change.
              8  The TEXT switch won't change.
              9  The PAGE2 switch won't change.
              A  The MIXMODE switch won't change.
              B  The HIRES switch won't change.

 If you receive an IOU FLAG E5 error, suspect the IOU at location E5.
```

(https://mirrors.apple2.org.za/Apple%20II%20Documentation%20Project/Companies/Apple/Documentation/Apple%20Technical%20Information%20Library/a2til139.txt)